# UISearchBAR scopeBar tintColor

Tags: uisearchbar

Has anyone managed to color the scopebar portion of a UISearchBar, it has a tintColor property but setting it does not affect the attached scopebar UISegmentedControl. Ive got a handle on the bar to tint it but doesnt seem to work ie:

```
for (id subview in searchBar.subviews){
  if([subview isMemberOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]){
     UISegmentedControl *scopeBar=(UISegmentedControl *) subview;
    scopeBar.tintColor=UIColorFromRGB(0x990066);
 }
}
```

Cheers, Neil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is interesting, turns out the scope bar is a somewhat customised segmented control.

From the docs: UISegmentedControl uses this property only if the style of the segmented control is UISegmentedControlStyleBar.

Now the scope bar segmented control *looks* like UISegmentedControlStyleBar but isn't, it's some undocumented style:

```
NSLog(@"scope bar style is %d", scopeBar.segmentedControlStyle);
> scope bar style is 7
```

You can try this, which does actually set the tint but it looks like arse:

```
[scopeBar setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
[scopeBar setTintColor: UIColorFromRGB(0x990066)];
> scope bar style is 2
```

Internally there are some instance variables influencing this: _segementedControlFlags.style and _barStyle but you cannot hack those unless you bypass the sanctioned API.

The best course of action is to raise it with Apple and hope they include a fix in a future release.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you said yourself, this really does look like arse.

Answer (score 9):

The above approaches weren't working for me and I ended up using an iOS appearance method.

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's some copy paste friendly code for what the others are discussing.

```
scopeBar.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar; //required for color change
for (id subview in self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews )
{
    if([subview isMemberOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]])
    {
        UISegmentedControl *scopeBar=(UISegmentedControl *) subview;
        scopeBar.tintColor =  [UIColor blackColor];         
    }
}
```

If you a white box like area around your buttons, you can change the color of that through interface builder.

I wouldn't say it looks "like ass" as the others do, but it isn't really ideal either.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the following to change the tint color of ScopeBar:

The below code is in C# (Xamarin)

```
SearchController.SearchBar.TintColor = UIColor.Green;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have *not* been able to get the tint set reliably for a scope bar.

What I've ended up doing is changing the search bar's `tintColor` ... UNTIL transitioning into search mode, at which point I make it the default color to match the scope bar. Then, when canceling the search, I change it back.

One spot that I seem to be missing here is the transition that occurs when the corresponding `tableView` is tapped, causing the search bar to lose first responder status. In that case, the color does not change back. Reason: I base that color change on having the search bar's cancel button being clicked.

Knee-jerk reaction: `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:` should get called (wherein we change back the tint) ... but that can't be right, because Cancel wasn't clicked. I really need a "Search is done" type of detection. Maybe just keep an eye on first responder and see when **UISearchBar** moves in and out of that state?

Answer (score 0):

Another band-aid solution to this problem (and a less complicated one) is you could add a semi-transparent UIImageView over the top of the Search bar and Scope bar and change the background color of the UIImageView to your desired tint color.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Change the tint color for changing color of scope bar. Note BarTintColor is different - this will change the color of the search bar..

Answer (score 0):

This solution is in Swift, can be adapted to objective-c. You can find the segmented control view using below function

```
func findSegmentedControl(view : UIView) -> UIView? {
    for v in view.subviews {
        if v is UISegmentedControl {
            print(v)
            return v
        } else {
            if let found = findSegmentedControl(view : v) {
                return found
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

and then set tint color of the view. calling this function will be like this:

```
if let segmentedView = findSegmentedControl(view: searchController.searchBar) {                
            segmentedView.tintColor = UIColor.white
        }
```