# UISearchDisplayController Scope Bar is gray not black like the search bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How do I set the color of the scope bar in a UISearchDisplayController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question to this SO one about a year ago: [UISearchBAR scopeBar tintColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661061/uisearchbar-scopebar-tintcolor)

I am not sure if much has changed in the way of clean support for this via API's, but the post above offers some hacky solutions that may work for you. Would love to see other possible solutions as well.